# Windows phone:Do not allow more than one dot in a textbox?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am writing application in windows phone 8.

I need to provide a textbox which will allow user to enter only "Numbers" and if required, only one dot ".

I set `<TextBox InputScope="Number" />` but it allow multiple dot.

How can i set single dot in textbox of windows phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an event that triggers everytime a text has change like this:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged" />
```

And then in the event function loop through the text, count the dots and if the dot count is higher than 1, delete the said dot.

EDIT: you said if I could provide a sample algorithm:

```
        string str = textBox1.Text;
        int dotCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == '.')
            {
                dotCount++;
                if (dotCount > 1)
                {
                    str.Remove(i, 1);
                    i--;
                    dotCount--;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is not working as it should so I made some improvements.. hope it helps! I'm using KeyUp but TextChange is also OK to use.

```
private void tbMainText_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender; //Getting the textbox which fired the event if you assigned many textboxes to the same event.
    string str = tb.Text;
    int dotCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '.')
        {
            dotCount++;
            if (dotCount > 1)
            {
                str = str.Remove(i, 1); //Assigning the new value.
                i--;
                dotCount--;
            }
        }
    }
    tb.Text = str;
    tb.Select(tb.Text.Length, 0); //Positioning the cursor at end of textbox.
}
```